# AppEngine - Search ndb by key inequality

Tags: google-app-engine, app-engine-ndb

How can one search for ndb models based on key inequality?

For example, for a string one can use:

```
 def add_inequality_filter(query, attr, given)
     end = given + u'\ufffd'
     return query.filter(attr >= given, attr < end)

 add_inequality_filter(query, "key", "abc.")
```

If `key` were an ordinary string property this would work, however the `key` is a [ModelKey](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/refdocs/modules/google/appengine/ext/ndb/model#ModelKey).

Comparing the `key` (or `_key`) to a string triggers a `BadValueError`.
There does not appear to be a documented way to create a `ModelKey` (or equivalent) for comparison.

When I try to filter on `__key__ >` (the `db` way) I get a `Cannot filter a non-Node argument`.

The [db to ndb](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python/ndb/db_to_ndb) documentation certainly indicates that this should be possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer my own question, the `given` and `end` in this need to be `ndb.Key` instances, whereas I had only attempted `ModelKey`, `KeyProperty` and strings.